# Multiple forms in Symfony. Display works but multiple persist

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I have a page with forms in hiddens modals.
Forms come from the same entity with different ids.
Displaying the modal works. For each modal I want to display, datas are ok inside inputs.
The issue is : when I submit the form, every forms (hidden included) are persisted.

```
//EditServiceType.php

namespace Guillaume\PartnerManagerBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class EditServiceType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', null, array(
                'label_attr' => array('class' => 'col-form-label'),
                'attr'       => array('class' => 'form-control')
            ))
            ->add('type')
            ->add('version')
            ->add('connection_type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'   => array(
                'Connected' => 2,
                'Local'    => 1,
            )));

    }/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Guillaume\PartnerManagerBundle\Entity\Service'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'edit_guillaume_partnermanagerbundle_service';
    }


}
```

Part of my Controller

```
$formEdits = [];
        $forms = [];
        $serviceFormEdits = [];
        foreach($services as $service) {
            $serviceFormEdits[$service->getId()] = $em->getRepository('GuillaumePartnerManagerBundle:Service')->find($service);
            $forms[$service->getId()]   = $this->createForm('Guillaume\PartnerManagerBundle\Form\EditServiceType', $serviceFormEdits[$service->getId()]);
            $formEdits[$service->getId()] = $forms[$service->getId()]->createView();

            $forms[$service->getId()]->handleRequest($request);
            if ($forms[$service->getId()]->isSubmitted() && $forms[$service->getId()]->isValid()) {

                    $em->persist($serviceFormEdits[$service->getId()]);
                    $em->flush();
                    $this->addFlash('notice', 'Service has been edited');
                }
            }
        }
//(...)

return $this->render('GuillaumePartnerManagerBundle:customers:customer.html.twig', [
'formEdits'           => $formEdits,
]);
```

Part of my twig (the modal)

```
{% for result in results %}
        {% form_theme formEdits[result.service.id] 'bootstrap_4_horizontal_layout.html.twig' %}
        <div class="modal fade" id="editEnvironment-{{ result.service.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">{{ 'Edit Environment'|trans }}</h2>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                 {{ form_start(formEdits[result.service.id]) }} 
                 <div class="form-group row">
                    {{ form_widget(formEdits[result.service.id]) }} 
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer row">
                     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" value="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">{{ 'Cancel'|trans }}</button>
                        <button type="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-primary">{{ 'Validate'|trans }}</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 {{ form_end(formEdits[result.service.id]) }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out.

adding 'id' in options resolver

```
$forms[$service->getId()]   = $this->createForm('Guillaume\PartnerManagerBundle\Form\EditServiceType', $serviceFormEdits[$service->getId()], ['id' => $service->getId()]);
```

adding input hidden in formType

```
    ->add('id', HiddenType::class, array(
        'data' => $options['id'],
        'mapped' => false,
    ))
```

and I use this id when submit is valid

```
            $postData = $request->request->get('edit_guillaume_partnermanagerbundle_service');
            $postId = $postData['id'];
            $forms[$postId]->handleRequest($request);

            if ($forms[$postId]->isSubmitted() && $forms[$postId]->isValid()) {

                        $em->persist($serviceFormEdits[$postId]);
                        $em->flush($serviceFormEdits[$postId]);
//(...)
```